# I want to add key & value by user input for dictionary if the value does not exist , in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, user-input, key-value

My dictionary

```
Phone_book = {
              'user1': 11111, 
              'user2': 22222, 
              'user3': 33333, 
              'user4': 44444, 
              'user5': 55555
             }
```

Search key by value

```
value = int(input('Number : '))
for k, v in Phone_book.items():
if value == v:
    print(k)
    break
```

Here I want to put the input by user

```
else:
print("number does not exist:")
print(phone_book(input["add user"])).split(), "=", input("write number") # something like this code, I know its wrong .
```

Answer (score 0):

I offer this as a trivial example of how you might approach this kind of thing if only to emphasise the importance of input validation.

```
Phone_book = dict()

while True:
    try:
        if (number := int(input('Enter a number (or 0 to end): '))) == 0:
            break
        if number in Phone_book.values():
            print(f'Number {number} already exists')
        else:
            if (name := input('Please enter a username: ')) == '' or name in Phone_book:
                print(f'Name {name} already exists or is invalid')
            else:
                Phone_book[name] = number
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input. Please try again')
        
print(Phone_book)
```